# FFmpeg Opus choppy sound UPDATED DESCRIPTION

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, resampling, opus

I'm using FFmpeg and try to encode and decode a raw PCM sound to Opus using a built-in FFmpeg "opus" codec. My input samples are raw PCM 8000 Hz 16 bit mono, in AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16 format. Since Opus requires sample format AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP and sample rate 48000 Hz only, so I resample my samples before encode them.

I have two instances of `ResamplerAudio` class that does the work of resampling audio samples and has a member of `SwrContext`, I use the first instance of `ResamplerAudio` for resampling a raw PCM input audio before encoding and the second for resampling decoded audio to get it's format and sample rate the same as source values of input raw audio.

ResamplerAudio class has a function that init it's SwrContext member like this:

```
void ResamplerAudio::init(AVCodecContext *codecContext, int inSampleRate, int outSampleRate, AVSampleFormat inSampleFmt, AVSampleFormat outSampleFmt)
{
    swrContext = swr_alloc();
    if (!swrContext)
    {
        LOGE(TAG, "[init] Couldn't allocate swr context");
        return;
    }

    av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "in_channel_layout", (int64_t) codecContext->channel_layout, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "out_channel_layout", (int64_t) codecContext->channel_layout,  0);

    av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "in_channel_count", codecContext->channels, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "out_channel_count", codecContext->channels, 0);

    av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "in_sample_rate", inSampleRate, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(swrContext, "out_sample_rate", outSampleRate, 0);

    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swrContext, "in_sample_fmt", inSampleFmt, 0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(swrContext, "out_sample_fmt", outSampleFmt,  0);

    int ret = swr_init(swrContext);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        LOGE(TAG, "[init] swr_init error: %s", av_err2str(ret));
        return;
    }

    LOGD(TAG, "[init] success codecContext->channel_layout: %d; inSampleRate: %d; outSampleRate: %d; inSampleFmt: %d; outSampleFmt: %d", (int) codecContext->channel_layout, inSampleRate, outSampleRate, inSampleFmt, outSampleFmt);
}
```

And I call `ResamplerAudio::init` function for the first instance of `ResamplerAudio` (this instance do resamping a raw PCM input audio before encoding and I called it `resamplerEncoder`) with the following args:

```
resamplerEncoder->init(contextEncoder, 8000, 48000, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP);
```

The second instance of `ResamplerAudio` (this instance do resamping after decoding audio from Opus and I called it `resamplerDecoder`) I init with the following args:

```
resamplerDecoder->init(contextDecoder, 48000, 8000, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16);
```

The function of `ResamplerAudio` that does resampling looks like this:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> ResamplerAudio::convert(uint8_t **inData, int inSamplesCount, int outChannels, int outFormat)
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> result;
    uint8_t *dstData = NULL;
    const int dstNbSamples = swr_get_out_samples(swrContext, inSamplesCount);
    av_samples_alloc(&dstData, NULL, outChannels, dstNbSamples, AVSampleFormat(outFormat), 1);
    int resampledSize = swr_convert(swrContext, &dstData, dstNbSamples, (const uint8_t **)inData, inSamplesCount);
    int dstBufSize = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, outChannels, resampledSize, AVSampleFormat(outFormat), 1);

    if (dstBufSize <= 0) return result;

    std::copy(&dstData[0], &dstData[dstBufSize], std::back_inserter(result));

    return result;
}
```

And I call `ResamplerAudio::convert` function before encoding with the following args:

```
// data - an array of raw pcm audio
// dataLength - the length of data array
// getSamplesCount() - function that calculates samples count
// frameEncode - AVFrame that using for encode audio
std::vector<uint8_t> resampledData = resamplerEncoder->convert(&data, getSamplesCount(dataLength, frameEncode->channels, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16), frameEncode->channels, frameEncode->format);
```

`getSamplesCount()` function looks like this:

```
getSamplesCount(int bytesCount, int channels, AVSampleFormat format)
{
    return bytesCount / av_get_bytes_per_sample(format) / channels;
}
```

After that I fill my `frameEncode` with resampled samples:

```
memcpy(&frame->data[0][0], &resampledData[0], sizeof(uint8_t) * resampledDataLength);
```

And pass `frameEncode` to encoding like this `encodeFrame(resampledDataLength)`:

```
void encodeFrame(int dataLength)
{
    /* send the frame for encoding */
    int ret = avcodec_send_frame(contextEncoder, frameEncode);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        LOGE(TAG, "[encodeFrame] avcodec_send_frame error: %s", av_err2str(ret));
        return;
    }

    /* read all the available output packets (in general there may be any number of them */
    while (ret >= 0)
    {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(contextEncoder, packetEncode);
        if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR(EAGAIN)) LOGE(TAG, "[encodeFrame] error in avcodec_receive_packet: %s", av_err2str(ret));
        if (ret < 0) break;

        // encodedData - std::vector<uint8_t> that stores encoded data
        std::copy(&packetEncode->data[0], &packetEncode->data[dataLength], std::back_inserter(encodedData));
        av_packet_unref(packetEncode);
    }
}
```

Then I decode my encoded samples and do resampling to get back them in source sample format and sample rate so I call `ResamplerAudio::convert` function for `resamplerDecoder` with the following args:

```
// frameDecode - AVFrame that holds decoded audio
std::vector<uint8_t> resampledData = resamplerDecoder->convert(frameDecode->data, frameDecode->nb_samples, frameDecode->channels, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16);
```

And result sound is choppy and I also noticed that the decoded array size is bigger than the source array size with raw pcm audio.

Please any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

### UPD 18.05.2020

I tested my resampling logic, I did resampling of raw pcm sound without any encoding and decoding routines. First I tried to convert the sample rate of input sound from 8000 Hz to 48000 Hz than I took resampled samples from step above and convert it's sample rate from 48000 Hz to 8000 Hz and the result sound is perfect and clean, also I did the same steps but I converted not a sample rate but a sample format from AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16 to AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP and vice versa and again the result sound is perfect and clean, also I got the same result when I coverted both a sample rate and a sample format.
So I assume that the problem of distorted and choppy sound is in my encoding or decoding routine, I think most likely in decoding routine because after decoding I **ALWAYS** get AVFrame with 960 nb_samples despite what was the size of input sound.

My decoding routine looks like this:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> decode(uint8_t *data, unsigned int dataLength)
{
    decodedData.clear();

    int dataSize = dataLength;

    while (dataSize > 0)
    {
        if (!frameDecode)
        {
            frameDecode = av_frame_alloc();
            if (!frameDecode)
            {
                LOGE(TAG, "[decode] Couldn't allocate the frame");
                return EMPTY_DATA;
            }
        }

        ret = av_parser_parse2(parser, contextDecoder, &packetDecode->data, &packetDecode->size, &data[0], dataSize, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            LOGE(TAG, "[decode] av_parser_parse2 error: %s", av_err2str(ret));
            return EMPTY_DATA;
        }

        data += ret;
        dataSize -= ret;

        doDecode();
    }
    return decodedData;
}

void doDecode()
{
    if (packetDecode->size) {
        /* send the packet with the compressed data to the decoder */
        int ret = avcodec_send_packet(contextDecoder, packetDecode);
        if (ret < 0) LOGE(TAG, "[decode] avcodec_send_packet error: %s", av_err2str(ret));

        /* read all the output frames (in general there may be any number of them */
        while (ret >= 0)
        {
            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(contextDecoder, frameDecode);
            if (ret < 0 && ret != AVERROR(EAGAIN) && ret != AVERROR_EOF) LOGE(TAG, "[decode] avcodec_receive_frame error: %s", av_err2str(ret));
            if (ret < 0) break;

            std::vector<uint8_t> resampledData = resamplerDecoder->convert(frameDecode->data, frameDecode->nb_samples, frameDecode->channels, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16);
            if (!resampledData.size()) continue;
            std::copy(&resampledData.data()[0], &resampledData.data()[resampledData.size()], std::back_inserter(decodedData));
        }
    }
}
```

### UPD 30.05.2020

I decided to refuse to use FFmpeg in my project and use [libopus 1.3.1](https://opus-codec.org/release/stable/2019/04/12/libopus-1_3_1.html) instead, so I made a [wrapper](https://github.com/theeasiestway/android-opus-codec) around it and it works fine.

Comment: Are you keeping 1 channel mono throughout or is a second channel being added for stereo somewhere?

Comment: @AnthumChris I'm keeping 1 channel, my input audio is mono and when I do resampling I specify also 1 channel

Comment: Please add the code where you set up `swrContext`

Comment: But what is in swrContext when you call swr_convert?  I think format and layout need to be correct.

Comment: @stark swrContext it's a member of class ResamplerAudio and I have two instances of ResamplerAudio: the first for resampling before encoding and the second for resampling after decoding

Comment: @stark I updated my answer and added encode and decode functions